# Sumar valores a una lista dependiendo del valor anterior

Tags: python, python-3.x

Voy a intentar explicarme, estoy haciendo practicas para aprender  con Python y quiero hacer una especie de ruleta y decir en que cuarto cae la bola después de el numero que salio en la ronda anterior.

La ruleta tiene del 0 al 36 y esta son divisiones de la ruleta:

```
PrimerCuarto=[32,15,19,4,21,2,25,17,34]
SegundoCuarto=[6,27,13,36,11,30,8,23,10]
TercerCuarto=[5,24,16,33,1,20,14,31,9]
CuartoCuarto=[22,18,29,7,28,12,35,3,26]
#Bolas
B0=[0,0,0,0]
B1=[0,0,0,0]
B2=[0,0,0,0]
B3=[0,0,0,0]
B4=[0,0,0,0]
B5=[0,0,0,0]
B6=[0,0,0,0]
B7=[0,0,0,0]
B8=[0,0,0,0]
B9=[0,0,0,0]
B10=[0,0,0,0]
B11=[0,0,0,0]
B12=[0,0,0,0]
B13=[0,0,0,0]
B14=[0,0,0,0]
B15=[0,0,0,0]
B16=[0,0,0,0]
B17=[0,0,0,0]
B18=[0,0,0,0]
B10=[0,0,0,0]
B20=[0,0,0,0]
B21=[0,0,0,0]
B22=[0,0,0,0]
B23=[0,0,0,0]
B24=[0,0,0,0]
B25=[0,0,0,0]
B26=[0,0,0,0]
B27=[0,0,0,0]
B28=[0,0,0,0]
B29=[0,0,0,0]
B30=[0,0,0,0]
B31=[0,0,0,0]
B32=[0,0,0,0]
B33=[0,0,0,0]
B34=[0,0,0,0]
B35=[0,0,0,0]
B36=[0,0,0,0]

ultimas_bolas=[1] #pongo un primer valor para que no de error
time.sleep(0.5)
bola=random.randint(0,36)
ultimas_bolas.insert(0,bola)
```

pongamos el ejemplo que ahora sale el 4 y anteriormente salio el 22, como el 4 esta en el Primer cuarto de la ruleta quiero sumar un +1 en la bola22 que seria la lista B22 y que quedara así la lista B22=[1,0,0,0] lo que quieres decir que sumamos un +1 al primer espacio de la lista b22 porque salio el 4 que esta en el primer cuarto, en 1000 tiradas puedo evaluar que cuarto sale con mas frecuencia después del numero que salio ahora

P.D ya se que es un jaleo  son solo practicas para aprender evidentemente el numero de cuarto que saldrá es aleatorio pero quiero aprender a almacenarlo se me ocurrió este ejemplo y así aprender de él.

### Edición

Basándome en la respuesta de @FJSevilla  hice un script mas entendible para mi y que vaya mas lento como simulando bolas reales , pero no logro que se sume el valor al diccionario siempre me sale `[0, 0, 0, 0]`.

Éste es mi nuevo código:

```
import random
import time

ultimas_bolas=[22,22]#pongo bolas anteriores para que no de error en la primera ejecución
dic_cuartos = {
     1: {32, 15, 19, 4, 21, 2, 25, 17, 34},
     2: {6, 27, 13, 36, 11, 30, 8, 23, 10},
     3: {5, 24, 16, 33, 1, 20, 14, 31, 9},
     4: {22, 18, 29, 7, 28, 12, 35, 3, 26}
     }

dic_bolas = {i: [0, 0, 0, 0] for i in range(37)}


ultima_bola = ultimas_bolas[1]

def principal():

   nueva_bola = random.randint(0, 36)
   ultimas_bolas.insert(0,nueva_bola)

   for cuarto, numeros in dic_cuartos.items():
      if nueva_bola in numeros:
         dic_bolas[ultima_bola][cuarto - 1] += 1


   print ("Bola anterior "+ str(ultimas_bolas[1])
          + " Ahora a salido el " +str(nueva_bola)
          + " y le sumamos +1 al cuarto correspondiente de la bola anterior"+ str(dic_bolas[0]) ) 

   time.sleep(1)

while 1==1:
   principal()
```

Comment: No tengo que usar variables, puedo usar diccionarios (nunca los use)es una pregunta parecida porque mas o menos quería explicar lo mismo jeje, lo intente con diccionario con tu ejemplo anterior pero no lo consigo, como seria? creo que con este ejemplo ya lo pillo si o si , gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si en vez de usar variables usas diccionarios te facilitas mucho la vida, además de ser la forma más comúnmente aceptada para solventar estos casos.

El diccionario de cuartos simplemente haz que las claves sean el número del cuarto (1, 2, 3, 4) y como valor podrías usar una lista, pero es mejor usar conjuntos, los números son únicos y los conjuntos son considerablemente más eficientes al buscar un elemento en ellos (tablas hash).

Para las bolas sería similar, como clave el número de bola, como valor la lista con los cuatro ceros.

```
import random


cuartos = {
     1: {32, 15, 19, 4, 21, 2, 25, 17, 34},
     2: {6, 27, 13, 36, 11, 30, 8, 23, 10},
     3: {5, 24, 16, 33, 1, 20, 14, 31, 9},
     4: {22, 18, 29, 7, 28, 12, 35, 3, 26}
     }

bolas = {i: [0, 0, 0, 0] for i in range(37)}


ultima_bola = random.randint(0, 36)
for _ in range(1000):
    nueva_bola = random.randint(0, 36)
    for cuarto, numeros in cuartos.items():
        if nueva_bola in numeros:
            bolas[ultima_bola][cuarto - 1] += 1 
    ultima_bola = nueva_bola
```

Puedes evitar el segundo `for` modificando el diccionario de cuartos, invirtiéndolo, de forma que las claves sena los número su el valor su cuarto:

```
import random


cuartos = {
    32: 0, 15: 0, 19: 0, 4: 0, 21: 0, 2: 0, 25: 0, 17: 0, 34: 0,
    6: 1, 27: 1, 13: 1, 36: 1, 11: 1, 30: 1, 8: 1, 23: 1, 10: 1,
    5: 2, 24: 2, 16: 2, 33: 2, 1: 2, 20: 2, 14: 2, 31: 2, 9: 2,
    22: 3, 18: 3, 29: 3, 7: 3, 28: 3, 12: 3, 35: 3, 3: 3, 26: 3
    }

bolas = {i: [0, 0, 0, 0] for i in range(37)}

ultima_bola = random.randint(0, 36)
for _ in range(1000):
    nueva_bola = random.randint(0, 36)
    if (cuarto := cuartos.get(nueva_bola)) is not None:
        bolas[ultima_bola][cuarto] += 1
    ultima_bola = nueva_bola
```

Ejemplo de ejecución:

> ```
> >>> bolas
>
> {0: [8, 9, 7, 7],
>  1: [10, 7, 3, 8],
>  2: [6, 8, 6, 9],
>  3: [2, 4, 7, 6],
>  4: [8, 2, 4, 7],
>  5: [8, 4, 12, 7],
>  6: [3, 7, 10, 8],
>  7: [7, 5, 4, 4],
>  8: [9, 6, 7, 6],
>  9: [6, 12, 5, 6],
>  10: [5, 5, 8, 7],
>  11: [2, 8, 7, 2],
>  12: [6, 6, 6, 10],
>  13: [11, 5, 3, 5],
>  14: [5, 5, 3, 5],
>  15: [5, 6, 8, 7],
>  16: [9, 6, 5, 5],
>  17: [6, 5, 6, 4],
>  18: [4, 9, 9, 12],
>  19: [3, 10, 11, 2],
>  20: [6, 5, 8, 5],
>  21: [5, 5, 5, 8],
>  22: [11, 6, 7, 8],
>  23: [5, 3, 4, 5],
>  24: [5, 7, 6, 10],
>  25: [4, 11, 6, 9],
>  26: [7, 5, 4, 5],
>  27: [6, 10, 5, 9],
>  28: [8, 9, 10, 11],
>  29: [9, 5, 9, 7],
>  30: [5, 8, 9, 8],
>  31: [4, 8, 4, 4],
>  32: [9, 5, 7, 4],
>  33: [9, 6, 5, 5],
>  34: [10, 5, 7, 9],
>  35: [4, 6, 3, 9],
>  36: [10, 6, 10, 6]}
> ```

### Edición

En tu nueva aproximación tienes dos problemas:

- El principal es que no modificas nunca `bola_anterior` dentro de la función en cada llamada, por lo que ésta siempre es 22. Esto hace que todas las bolas terminen en el diccionario de la bola 22...
- Lo segundo es que en el `print` siempre imprimes la bola 0 (`dic_bolas[0]`)

---

```
import random
import time


ultimas_bolas = [22, 22]
dic_cuartos = {
     1: {32, 15, 19, 4, 21, 2, 25, 17, 34},
     2: {6, 27, 13, 36, 11, 30, 8, 23, 10},
     3: {5, 24, 16, 33, 1, 20, 14, 31, 9},
     4: {22, 18, 29, 7, 28, 12, 35, 3, 26}
     }

dic_bolas = {i: [0, 0, 0, 0] for i in range(37)}


def principal():
    nueva_bola = random.randint(0, 36)
    ultima_bola = ultimas_bolas[-2]  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    ultimas_bolas.append(nueva_bola)

    for cuarto, numeros in dic_cuartos.items():
        if nueva_bola in numeros:
            dic_bolas[ultima_bola][cuarto - 1] += 1

    print((f"Bola anterior {ultimas_bolas[-2]}. "
           f"Ahora a salido el {nueva_bola} y le sumamos +1 al cuarto "
           f"correspondiente de la bola anterior {dic_bolas[ultima_bola]}")
          )

    time.sleep(1)


while True:
    principal()
```

Comment: Perfecto gracias! basándome en tu script hice uno mas entendible para mi y que vaya mas lento como simulando bolas reales , pero no logro que se sume el valor al diccionario siempre me sale 0,0,0,0.